# How to maximize chrome browser using intern leadfoot

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

I am having hard time maximizing chrome browser using theintern/leadfoot command 
maximize.

I tried maximize window `.maximizeWindow()` (it works for firefox but not for chrome browser. I even tried `execute("window.resizeTo(14400, 8130);")`
and `setWindowSize("", 1440, 813);`

Has any one tried a different approach?

Comment: Might've been fixed. `.maximizeWindow()` works for me, Chrome 49.0.2623.110

Answer (score 0):

You can add Chrome commandline argument `--start-maximized`, you can pass it in `chromeOptions`

```
{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [
            'start-maximized'
        ]
    }
}
```